# QtOpenGL: No such file or directory opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, opengl

when i use make commande i get this error

```
[ 24%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o
In file included from /home/sharkawey/op/opencv-master/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:47:0:
/home/sharkawey/op/opencv-master/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.h:46:20: fatal error: QtOpenGL: No such file or directory
 #include <QtOpenGL>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i used this command to compile opencv

```
 cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON  

        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON

        -D WITH_QT=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local

        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON

        -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON ..
```

but the proplem still here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you added your Qt folder to your path? 
Anyway, doing some change like these should help:

1. Go to path '`/home/sharkawey/op/opencv-master/modules/highgui/src/`'.
2. Open file '`window_QT.h`' with your editor.
3. Change the following line:

`#include <QtOpenGL>`

into:

```
#include <fullpath/QtOpenGL>
```

Replace the 'fullpath' string with your actual path of QtOpenGL. You can find it using find command. For instance, if your `QtOpenGL` is located under '`/home/usr/Qt/`', you should write as:

```
#include </home/usr/Qt/QtOpenGL>
```

Then your compiler knows where to find it. I believe for your case, you may encounter same situations for other files too, and you can solve them similarly.

Comment: its still give me erorr i use qt5

Comment: Did you receive a different error message or again the same one? Are you sure you provided the correct full path as described?

Answer (score 9):

You need to install missing dependencies, which can be done by:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5opengl5 libqt5opengl5-dev
```